# What is the best way to update a subscription on the back-end using Stripe's webhooks?

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

What event should my webhook look for in order to update a customer's subscription in my database? I would assume `customer.subscription.updated` as it contains the `current_period_start` and `current_period_end` items. However, my concern is that `customer.subscription.updated` is apparently fired an hour or so before `invoice.payment_succeeded` is fired. I wouldn't want to update a customer's subscription if the payment then failed an hour later.

Comment: I would listen for and update my app's subscription state with `invoice.payment_succeeded` or `invoice.payment_failed` --- that way you'd know whether or not the sub is paid for the next period or not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [duck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5108826) stated in his/her comment, I think the best way to update a subscription if the payment of the invoice failed or succeeded is to listen to these events:

- [`invoice.payment_succeeded`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-invoice.payment_succeeded): Occurs whenever an invoice payment attempt succeeds.
- [`invoice.payment_failed`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-invoice.payment_failed): Occurs whenever an invoice payment attempt fails, due either to a declined payment or to the lack of a stored payment method.

Actually this is the way I handle things in production, and it is very effective. I would recommend the Stripe documentation's article [Billing Lifecycle and Events](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/lifecycle), especially the section [The subscription lifecycle](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/lifecycle#subscription-lifecycle):

> After this first invoice, the following cycle of events repeats every
>   billing period:
>
> 1. When the subscription approaches its renewal date, an `invoice.upcoming` event is sent.
> 2. When the subscription period elapses, an `invoice.created` event is sent, indicating the creation of a draft invoice.
> 3. About an hour after the invoice is created, it is finalized (changes are no longer permitted), and an `invoice.finalized` event is
>      sent. A charge is attempted, and a `charge.succeeded` event is sent to
>      indicate that the payment was successful.
> 4. An `invoice.payment_succeeded` event is sent to indicate that the invoice was marked paid.

Comment: Basing this decision on `invoice.payment_failed` and `invoice.payment_succeeded` does not feel entirely right. Stripe gives an option to attempt "Smart Tries". It also gives the option to change the status of subscription to `unpaid` if X number of tries fail in Y number of days. So ideally, the `unpaid` status of a subscription should be used. Is there an event for it? Or what is the best way to tackle this scenario by using the aforementioned invoice events?